# Graphic Design - Video games -- events, seminars, workshops, etc

Tags: resource-recommendations

My daughter loves drawing - using pencil.  She wants to be a Graphic Designer - mainly for video games area.  We got her a drawing tablet, but she is more comfortable using the pencil.  I have not idea if GD is the best thing for her, &/or how I can help her.  Are there any events, seminars, she could attend to?  She is in 10th grade now... I want to make sure this is really what she wants to do. I don't want her to realize later on, it is not really what she thought she was going into.

Thank you
B

Comment: Of course there are events. Could you edit this to be more specific as to what you're looking for? We can't just list every graphic design event around, there's literally thousands of them around the world.

Comment: Sorry --- Events, workshops, seminars, etc - in the NY, NJ area.  I would like for her to see and hear general information in Graphic Design - anything hands on would be great.

Comment: I think this is a bit too broad and too localized to be a good question. I understand the inquiry, I just don't think it fits the StackExchange format -- especially due to the localization.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is still very broad but to try and help you out. NYC is a capital of the design world, you'd be hard-pressed to have a single weekend without some sort of design event. As far as hands-on for kids, that's getting a bit more specific.

You might want to look into http://aigany.org/get-involved/mentoring/ though it sounds like at least initially it will only be open to students at New York City High School of Art and Design but it never hurts to inquire. They might know another option for you.

Again you're in the design mecca. Look at any number of schools and they probably have a program for her. The first (and only one) I looked at is FIT and sure enough: http://fitnyc.edu/5915.asp

You could probably find similar programs at Parsons, Pratt, Cooper Union (maybe?), SUNY, RIT, RPI, Rutgers, Syracuse, and everywhere else.

Then there's private tutors. Or just call up a few designers and see if any would be willing to let her sit-in for a day or two at their office.

Answer (score 0):

If it works out, get her into a quality art school. The first few years she'll get plenty of introduction to a wide range of art professions, along with getting her generals out of the way as well.

In the interim, if she's *really* into the idea of game design and if she has even a bit of interest in it--suggest she start taking some computer science classes if they are offered in highschool. You don't have to be a programmer to be a game designer, but if the aptitude and interest is there, it's going to be a skill that will only benefit her.